ERROR Error sending to server: [AxiosError: Network Error]
I'm working on a react native project with expo, and when uploading an image to the server via expo go on the Iphone it inserts correctly. I get the success message. However, when I try to do the same process on an Android phone, it returns the error: ERROR Error sending to server: [AxiosError: Network Error].
I've been trying for a long time to figure out what I wear that by postman goes, by iphone at expo go goes. Only on Android phone that doesn't.
